# How to make changes in Plugin online

Tags: jquery

I am using [this](http://maps.seatics.com/maincontrol_tn.js) in my application.In this I'm using a `<div id="ssc_listAndMapDiv">`.

Now according to my requirement I have to put one div in this div.But as the Javascript file is online, how can I make changes in this js file.

Comment: Do you mean with 'this' your own page and js file?

Comment: `Shilpa` I had a crush with same name once :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append)

```
$('#ssc_listAndMapDiv').append('<div> you div here</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If youve got the licences to do that, you can simply save the js locally (right click on [THIS](http://maps.seatics.com/maincontrol_tn.js) and save destination as... and modify the local script... it seems that its a compressed javascript so you may search for uncompressing methods  or another version of that js whitout compression.

see also > http://jsbeautifier.org/ to decompress the js

Comment: ...and if you haven't got the license, the deeplinking of and relying on another one's JS file is daring and illegal at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely vague. It would help tremendously if you put in more information, such as what you're trying to accomplish, what's not working, and why you're looking to change the JavaScript file.

Now, if you really do need to change the plugin itself, then, if the license allows, you need to download a non-minified version and make your changes accordingly.

If you need to add something to make the plugin work (such as something in `$(document).ready()`), then you don't have to edit the plugin's JavaScript, just have your own JavaScript file that you put those commands in and link to it in your HTML after the library files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome(-ium) dev tools to make changes in files real-time. About it you can watch in youtube @ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8SS-rUEZPg